# Elseworlds comic where Superman was the richest athlete in the world

Tags: dc, comics, superman, episode-identification

I vaguely recall a 1990s comic where something happened differently, and Clark Kent ended up not becoming a hero who rescues people and inspires Hope, but a *sports hero* and one of the richest, most bankable men on the planet; he played Basketball, Baseball, **and** Football, if I remember correctly.  Started reading it at a friends place, but never finished.

Can someone identify this story and issue, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Superman, Inc.](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman,_Inc.) (1999).

Superman is adopted by the Sudermans and becomes Dale Suderman, ace sportsman. The comic is explicitly noted to be an Elseworlds comic.

[image]

His sporting prowess extends to basketball, baseball, American football and he's also an Olympian.

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you, V-Dawg. Now all I need to understand is how the **hell** they managed to give him that duchie haircut....and _why!_

Comment: He was so good with a baseball bat, some called him simply "The Bat-Man".